# Airflow and Docker: Working on container or local files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I have an app consisting of AI models trained with Ray and MLflow procedures. The app exposes APIs on a UI dashboard, which allows performing AI inference on new data via trained model. The UI is exposed to the client, while the training procedures are managed by developers. To automate training, DAGs were written to perform data processing and validation, model auto-tuning and training.

I'm not sure how to set up Airflow here. It is currently launched via Docker Compose (DC), and I see 2 options for interacting with it:

- **Option 1**: the DC file includes the app service. The app consists of scripts to train models which are mapped between the container and the local file system (volume mounting). `BashOperators` are used to perform training tasks directly in the app container. An extended image of Airflow installs python dependencies for data validations only.
- **Option 2**: the DC file includes an extended image of Airflow, for which all requirements are installed to perform model training, processing, etc... but the app service is not included. Here, local files and folders are mounted to the airflow containers.

Any idea what would be the best approach with Airflow?